# Img src doesn't change when i updated the source

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic 1 app and im trying to dynamically change a img source. I thought all i had to do whas update the scope linked to this source, but it doesn't worked. Any idea on what might be wrong?

```
my View
<div ng-if="isList" class="item style-list" ng-repeat="(key, item) in items"
       ng-click="goTo(item)">
            <div class="img-container" ng-if="isList">
                <m-img encode="true" src="item.image"></m-img>
            </div>
    <h1 ng-bind="item.title"></h1>
            <p ng-bind="item.resume" ng-if="item.resume"></p>
            <p ng-bind-html="stripHtml(item.description) | mCut:100" ng-if="!item.resume"></p>
  </div>

my Controller
     $scope.$on("update-data", function(event, args) { 

      $scope.items[1].description = 
      args.response.results[0].item.description;
      $scope.items[1].id = args.response.results[0].item.id;
      $scope.items[1].image = args.response.results[0].item.image;
      $scope.items[1].resume = args.response.results[0].item.resume;
      $scope.items[1].title = args.response.results[0].item.title;

    });
```

My m-img component

```
html
<div class="thumb-size notloaded">
  <div class="thumb" ng-if="imgStyle" ion-img-cache-bg ng-
style="imgStyle">
    </div>
</div>
```

My m-img JS is kinda extensive, here https://codeshare.io/adABMe

Comment: post the code of m-img component

Comment: Just posted it!

Comment: I haven’t worked with Ionic before, but have you tried [using ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)?

Comment: I did, same results : / , as Karim pointed it might be something related to my m-img component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that the error is inside mImg component, from the code [here](https://codeshare.io/adABMe) you're not watching changes on `src` attribute (but you're doing it only on `url` attribute that here is not used) and you're triggering some logic (defined in `$scope.load`) to update the view.

You should add a watcher even on `src` and trigger your load method to update `$scope.imgSrc` variable , this should update your view consequently

```
controller: function($scope, $timeout, $mAppDef) {
   $scope.$watch('src', function() {
     $scope.load()
   });
}
```